# Wordpress register api internal server error (err:500)

Tags: ios, wordpress

```
{"error":"500","reason":"Internal Server Error","detail":"Mandatory parameter os missing"}
```

whlie calling register api in wordpress

Comment: you forgot to send Mandatory parameter that need on server for response of your request

Comment: Are you sure [**iOS**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) tag is relevant with this question?

Comment: ya I'm trying in iOS, I'm sending all mandatory parameter including 'os' still getting same error.